# Optimizing join query performance in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**Scenario**

- Entity1 (id,itmname)
- Entity2 (id,itmname,price)
- Entity3 (id,itmname,profit)
- **profit and price are both IntegerProperty**

I want to count all the item with price more then 500 and profit more then 10.

I know its join operation and is not supported by google. I tried my best to find out the way other then executing queries separately and performing count but I didn't get anything.

The reason for not executing queries separately is query execution time. In each query I am getting more then 50000 records as result so it takes nearly 20 seconds in fetching records from first query.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine developers have always focused on read optimization and that is one thing where denormalization pops in. Before you design your data structure, you should work on possible cases in which the data could be retrieved. Designing of models comes later. A closer look at I/O session about 
[Building Scalable Web Applications with Google App Engine](http://sites.google.com/site/io/building-scalable-web-applications-with-google-app-engine) will prove helpful.

In the current situation, if you are interested in *just* the counts, you may go with a [shard counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html). It will require you to update every associated counter if the field updates.

Another approach involves performing nightly scheduled task which will do heavy calculations, and update counts and other stats you might need. You might find [mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) helpful in this case. This approach will never give you real time data.

Comment: mapreduce and shard counter is not useful in my case as i want to display results to the user in realtime.. Also do u kn any way to optimize performance with this situation..

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to this problem is denormalization.  Try storing a copy of `price` and `profit` in `Entity1` and then you can answer your question with a single, simple query on `Entity1`.

Comment: thnks for ur answer, its really great. But here its just an scenario what if entity2 and entity3 having 15 to 20 properties and queriy can be of any combination of properties of entity2 and entity3.

Comment: @mahesh: the App Engine datastore is fairly bad at ad hoc queries like that. At best, you're looking at building composite indexes for every possible combination of properties, making your indexes take up many orders of magnitude more storage space than your actual data.  The best solution is probably to replicate your data to an SQL database somewhere else, or wait for SQL on App Engine.

Comment: re sql comment above: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/9740dd2a8bdf4206  Could always try that and hope you're lucky.  :)